# Build fails because of xml documentation error

Tags: tfsbuild

I am trying to build a ASP.NET MVC 2 project that uses Lucene.Net. I make a standard build definition in TFS 2010. When I queue a new build, it fails on this error:

**CSC: Error generating XML documentation file 'xxx\xxx\Lucene.Net.xml' ('Access is denied. ')**

But in my project properties for Lucene, I don't have xml comments checked. How can I get this to build correctly? I don't care about xml document files!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. Unchecked it on release build config, and all is fine.

Comment: can you maybe add a little more detail with your answer?  It's not very clear to other people who might be doing the same thing.

Comment: I unchecked the xml documentation checkbox in the project properties.

Comment: In my case, I switched to "Debug" mode and the build worked.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. In my case it was caused by having bin\Release\[Assembly Name].xml in project Source Control. In build Sources location the [Assembly Name].xml was marked as readonly and CSC cannot override it.

Solution is to remove [Assembly Name].xml file from Source Control, or set Cloak in Workspace option of Build definition.